# Setting list variable in Robot

Tags: robotframework

I'm learning about Robot framework from course on Udemy and strangely
I'm getting error when I'm not supposed be getting error.

```
*** Variables ***
${VAR}  4
${VAR2}  4
@{VARL}  ['python', 'robot']

*** Test Cases ***
TC_001
    [Documentation]  Using scalar variable
    Should Be Equal  ${VAR}  ${VAR2}

TC_002
    Should Not Be Equal As Strings  @{VARL}[0]  @{VARL}[1]
```

When running the test on TC_002 I'm getting `List '@{VARL}' has no item in index 1.`

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Use keywords `Log List` and `Get Count` to see what's inside `${VARL}` variable and you'll see that it's list with one element

Comment: The question is  is the list variable declared correctly. It should but I might've missed something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your definition of `@{VARL}` is not correct - you don't need the square brackets, but just provide the different members with at least two spaces between each:

```
*** Variables ***
@{VARL}    python    robot
```